# How to communicate a position as a Google Maps URL?

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to show someone a specific point on Google Maps. How can I put down a pin (and remove all other pins) and get a URL of the resulting map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also share the map by centering your view on the location you right-click.  Once this is done, you can then link to the maps by clicking the link icon (looks like a chain segment) in the upper right corner.  This will re-create your viewed location anytime you go to the URL it gives you.

Comment: I'd like to point to a specific point on the map. It's hard to see what it is centered on.

Comment: Try right clicking the location, click "What's here?" and Google Maps will drop a pinpoint down.  Then click the "Link" chain-symbol in the upper right corner and copy the URL.  That should retain the drop-pin.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer since it works with arbitrary points (not just pre-determined addresses) and doesn't rely on external webapps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a page which illustrates sharing a location on Google Maps: [A Guide To Sharing or Linking to a Google Map ( Yes, you read it right! )](http://www.guidingtech.com/4125/share-link-to-google-maps/).

To remove all the pins(placemarker's to be specific) you could hover over photos and uncheck 'Labels' in the dropdown list.